# Why is the "i++" a dead code here in the below snippet?

Tags: java, dead-code

While coding with eclipse, the code i++ is shown as a dead code. What does that mean? Why is it being a dead code?

```
public class ScoreCalculator{
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int ScoreCard[] = {70,102,198, 60};
        String PlayersList[] = {"Mukesh","Suresh","Shardul","Nandan"};
        System.out.println(DisplayScore(ScoreCard, PlayersList));

    }

    public static String DisplayScore(int[] Scores, String[] Players){

        for( int i=0; i <= 3; i++){

            if(Scores[i]>100 && Scores[i]<=200){

                System.out.println("\n******Players who moved to next level******");
                return Players[i] + "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("\n******Players in Danger Level******");
                return Players[i] + "\n";
            }

        }
        return "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because return will break the loop in first iteration

Answer (score 3):

In all possible flows you exit the loop before performing that `i++`. There are three different possible flows:

1. You don't enter the loop (*just theoretical - in your case you enter*).
2. You enter and the condition is true - immediate return in if block.
3. You enter and the condition is false - immediate return in else block.

In all cases, you don't finish the single loop, so the code which is evaluated after each iteration, isn't reachable.

And the `for` loop works as the following:

```
for (A; B; C)
    ^^ - executes before the loop starts (before first iteration
        ^^ - is evaluated before each iteration
           ^^ is evaluated after each full iteration, so is executed in case the loop executes
              at least once
```

Personally, I'm really impressed that the IDE has spotted it.

Answer (score 0):

The first iteration of a loop will return a value, breaking from the method. Thus, increment never happens.

This loop is equivalent to it's first iteration:

```
if(Scores[0]>100 && Scores[0]<=200){
    System.out.println("\n******Players who moved to next level******");
} else {
    System.out.println("\n******Players in Danger Level******");
}
return Players[0] + "\n";
```